# updating kernel 5.8 to 5.11 ubuntu 20.1 wont boot

Tags: kernel, 20.10

so i tried to update my ubuntu 20.10 from kernel 5.8 to 5.11 and i am getting this error on reboot after i had completed the steps found on a webstie that referenced ubuntu.com lib. here is the error /boot/vmlinz-5.11.0-051100-generic has invalid signature.
error you need to load the kernel first.

then i hit contimnue and i get 3 options, i am able to boot with the 5.8 but 5.11 will not load. help.

i am very new to ubuntu. so i would have no idea on how to fix it or where to start.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the steps you followed to update your kernel? This will make it easier to know where/why the error may be occurring 

Comment: As a new Ubuntu user, you just learned the first basic rule... don't install software outside of the Ubuntu repos... especially if you don't have enough experience to be able to repair boo boos. For now, boot to the 5.8 kernel, then delete the 5.11 stuff.

Comment: Please clarify or correct details. Ubuntu uses a *year.month* format for desktop & server releases (*year* is used for specialist releases), and there was no Ubuntu released in 2020-January (ie. 20.1).  You tagged 20.10 (there was a release in 2020-October) but 1 is not 10, so it could be possible you made a couple of typos, or you're using a fake OS.   (just as 5.8 goes before  5.11 (the numbers aren't decimal; 5.11 = 5.eleven), 20.1 is not 20.10 (20.one != 20.ten)

Comment: sorry, i did not know i had to clarify exactly, like i said i am very new from windows and wanting better security and less spying. here is the steps i took. https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu this is 20.10 my apologies.

Comment: No apology is necessary; being accurate allows us to clearly understand & provide better & more accurate help for you.  There are also 'fake' download sites etc. and imprecise details often show people going to the *fake* sites..  (title too)

Comment: i do not know how to sign the kernel, can someone please advise me on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the kernel or disable secure boot in BIOS

Comment: i do not know how to do that, can you advise on how to  sign the kernel  please?